# How to get reference to Youtube Iframe API player throughout Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube-api

I've been digging around the Stack Overflow threads, and can't seem to find this issue addressed exactly. I set up and Angular app, and I would like to be able to call methods on a YouTube API from within multiple controllers and directives (such as `playVideo()` and `pauseVideo()` etc)

The video will be persistent throughout the site.

I initially set up the API via a service and subsequently injected it into the various controllers. I used a `$rootscope.$broadcast` to send a message when the player was ready, but I could never get the actual player returned, just an empty object.

To make matters worse, I rebuilt the site statically so have no example code to show here, but was hoping someone might be able to outline the basic procedure here.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2):

[YouTube Topic explorer](https://code.google.com/p/yt-topic-explorer/source/browse/app/scripts/controllers/main.js) uses iframe inside the angular script. You can basically create your own function or directive to use the iFrame.